# Why is the type of inheritance required to be primary key (PK) for relationship types in SERM (ERM) modeling?

Tags: database, data-modeling, modeling, entity-relationship, serm

[SERM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_entity_relationship_model) is an extension of ERM.

There are two types of inheritance, that is, how dependent entities/relationships inherit the primary key from the superior entity:

1. For the dependent entity/relationship, the foreign (inherited) key becomes part of the primary key ("PK").
2. For the dependent entity/relationship, the foreign (inherited) key does *not* become a part of the primary key ("FK").

Now, I understand there are multiple options for dependent ER-types as it's possible to use an artificial value as primary key (such as an auto-incrementing index, surrogate key).

I don't understand, however, why relationship types are required to always use the foreign key as part of their primary key (type of inheritance = "PK"). Why is it not possible to use a surrogate primary key and store the foreign key in some other attribute for relationship types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the answer to this question is pretty trivial: relationship types generally don't have their own primary key attributes.

Although this does not explain it's forbidden to use FK-inheritance, it explains why it is common to use PK-inheritance.

Since a relationship, by definition, models the relation between entities, it doesn't make sense for it to have its own primary key attribute (otherwise, it would be an entity as well).